# d3.js: how can I get 'full width' ticks on the y-axis

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm using this reusable column chart, with some modifications:
https://gist.github.com/llad/3766585

```
/* Reusable column chart for d3.js          */
/*    https://gist.github.com/llad/3766585  */

function columnChart() {
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
      width = 420,
      height = 420,
      xRoundBands = 0.2,
      xValue = function(d) { return d[0]; },
      yValue = function(d) { return d[1]; },
      xScale = d3.scale.ordinal(),
      yScale = d3.scale.linear(),
      xFormat = '',
      yFormat = '',
      yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left"),
      xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);


  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

      // Convert data to standard representation greedily;
      // this is needed for nondeterministic accessors.
      data = data.map(function(d, i) {
        return [xValue.call(data, d, i), yValue.call(data, d, i)];
      });

      // Update the x-scale.
      xScale
          .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0];} ))
          .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], xRoundBands);


      // Update the y-scale.
      yScale
          .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} )))
          .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
          .nice();


      // Select the svg element, if it exists.
      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

      // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
      var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "bars");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis zero");

      // Update the outer dimensions.
      svg .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

      // Update the inner dimensions.
      var g = svg.select("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

     // Update the bars.
      var bar = svg.select(".bars").selectAll(".bar").data(data);
      bar.enter().append("rect");
      bar.exit().remove();
      bar.attr("class", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive"; })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return X(d); })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? Y0() : Y(d); })
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function(d, i) { return Math.abs( Y(d) - Y0() ); })
        .on("click", function(d, i) 
        {
            d3.selectAll('.bar').classed('fade', true);
            d3.select(this).classed("sel", true).classed("fade", false);
        })
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) 
        {
            d3.select(this).classed("hover", true);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d, i) 
        {
            d3.select(this).classed("hover", false);
        });

    // x axis at the bottom of the chart
     g.select(".x.axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis.orient("bottom").tickFormat(xFormat));

    // zero line
     g.select(".x.axis.zero")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + Y0() + ")")
        .call(xAxis.tickFormat("").tickSize(0));


      // Update the y-axis.
      g.select(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    });
  }


// The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale ∘ xValue.
  function X(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  }

  function Y0() {
    return yScale(0);
  }

  // The x-accessor for the path generator; yScale ∘ yValue.
  function Y(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  }

  chart.margin = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return margin;
    margin = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.width = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.x = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
    xValue = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.y = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
    yValue = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.yTickFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return yFormat;
    yFormat = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.xTickFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return xFormat;
    xFormat = _;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

It's a nice little script! I've added the xTickFormat and click and mouseover functions.

However, on column charts I like to have faint horizontal lines going the full width of the chart, essentially extending the y-axis ticks to the full width.

1. How do modify the yAxis to get these full width lines, or an option to have those lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/Jqmzd/2/

The key is the `.tickSize()` property.

Comment: That looks too easy! Follow on question so I can understand how these pieces work: What is the difference between the ticks on the axis (black) and the ticks that make the grid (light gray)? Why doesn't it just make the ticks longer? Obviously they're generated as separate shapes... but how/why?

Comment: OK, dissecting it a bit more, I see the grid you added is separate from the axis, and I can see how keeping them separate is beneficial. Thanks Sam

Comment: Right. You can choose to have either vertical or horizontal, or both. And you're welcome :)

Comment: make sure to use a negative number here
`.tickSize(-innerHeight);`
 `.tickSize(-innerWidth);`